# "format" true/false to something like "yes/no" in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Note that I'm only looking to "format" the info.

Background: we have a Google Sheet that downloads raw info from a BigQuery table. One of the fields is Boolean so the results show "true"/"false".

We have another tab on that GS that does a query. For display purposes, we'd like to show something like "Y/N" or maybe even "X""(blank)" instead of "True/False. We could create like a helper column on the tab that contains the BigQuery info to change true/false to what we want, and then query off of that, but the raw data is already pretty big and we'd prefer not to keep adding more columns if we can help it.

Here's a sample [GS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12_5moxs8rFUxIkfN1cpRfN7xmq6Gde3kBz5vVEEZaFU/edit?usp=sharing)

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Probably a simple script could be written to iterate down your column that you could program to run whenever you pull from Big query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A=""; "X"; IF(A1:A=TRUE; "Y"; "N")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Logical values can be represented as check boxes. Useful for input values, but it can also be used on output values.

Menus > Insert > Check box (or Tick box)

[image: Insert checkboxes]